# Custom check in clang-tidy not available

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-tidy

I wanted to add a custom check to clang-tidy so I followed the official documentation using the command `clang-tidy/add_new_check.py misc passes` (https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html)

Check is registered in CMakeLists.txt and MiscTidyModule.cpp

[image: The new check named passes registered inside CMakeLists.txt]

[image: Check registered in MiscTidyModule.cpp as well]

The check is still not available with clang-tidy - `clang-tidy -checks="*" --list-checks | grep passes`

Comment: After editing those files, what command did you run to recompile?  Did it create a new `clang-tidy` with a recent timestamp?  Is there any output from `strings clang-tidy | grep misc-passes`?

Comment: I build the entire code using  by cd into `/clang-llvm/llvm-project/build` and then `ninja`. `clang-tidy -checks="*" --list-checks | grep passes` doesn't return anything. I think I'm asking a really basic question but how/where should I check if new clang-tidy is generated? or if I'm not building clang-tidy correctly.

Comment: After running `ninja` in the `build` directory, there should now be a file called `bin/clang-tidy` with a timestamp more recent than when you edited those files.  If you don't see `clang-tidy` there, but you do see other programs like `clang`, then you might have invoked `cmake` incorrectly; you need to have passed `-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra"` to it in order to enable the `clang-tools-extra` project, which `clang-tidy` is a part of.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I run the clang-tidy from `build/bin/clang-tidy` the changes are reflected. I was previously running clang-tidy which was installed and not the one that was getting build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As now explained in the comments, the problem was due to invoking the originally installed `clang-tidy` rather than the one built from the modified sources.  The latter is found in `$BUILD/bin/clang-tidy` where `$BUILD` is the directory in which `cmake` was run.

To make this Q+A potentially more useful to others, I'll summarize some relevant troubleshooting:

- If `$BUILD/bin/clang-tidy` is missing but other programs like `$BUILD/bin/clang` are present, the problem is likely due to how `cmake` was invoked.  In particular, one must pass `-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra"` to `cmake` in order to enable the `clang-tools-extra` project, of which `clang-tidy` is a part.
- If you have a `clang-tidy`, you can run the [`strings`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix)) program on it to see if string literals from your custom check are present in the binary.  If not, then the problem is likely related to the build system, such as a missing entry in `CMakeLists.txt` or failing to re-run the build properly.
- If the check has been linked in, then it should appear in the output of `$BUILD/bin/clang-tidy -checks="*" --list-checks`.  If it does not, then the problem is likely with how the check is being registered (with `registerCheck`; see [`ClangTidyCheckFactories`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/doxygen/classclang_1_1tidy_1_1ClangTidyCheckFactories.html)).